# Вопросы по верстке email писем

Tags: html, вёрстка, вёрстка-email

В качестве примера использовано [письмо](http://mailchi.mp/htmlacademy/html-academy-709705?e=bf08e38108) из рассылки HTML Academy.

1. В начало добавлено две таблицы с классом `email-width`. Они выполняют роль отступа сверху и "распорки" по ширине, для главной таблицы? Почему две?

   [image]
2. Можно ли таблицы заменить на строку с ячейкой?

   ```
   <table class="email-width">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

```
    <tr>
      <td class="email-width"></td>
    </tr>
```

3. *Элемент `tbody` предназначен для хранения строк таблицы. Это позволяет создавать структурные блоки, к которым можно применять единое оформление через стили.*
   Для чего в каждой таблице используется тег tbody, если в некоторых из них всего одна строка?
4. Можно ли создать верстку подобного письма с использованием одной таблицы, а внутреннюю структуру(header, content, footer) с помощью строк и ячеек? Правильно ли это будет?
5. Если использование одной таблицы неправильно, то по какому принципу определяем, когда можно обойтись ***tr***, ***td***, а когда в структуру письма необходимо включит ***table***?

Comment: Задавайте по 1 вопросу в вопросе.

Comment: Используйте mjml.io и не парьтесь с письмами...

Comment: Вот здесь все подробно описано, какие свойства какие мейл клиенты поддерживают. наверное будет достаточно https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вёрстки писем очень широкая. Правильно будет не то, что считается правильным *при верстке для сайтов*, а то, что *будет правильно отображаться* у ваших клиентов, пользующихся каким-нибудь старым Outlook Express. Это сделать само по себе сложно и не всегда возможно.

Если у всех получателей ваших писем они отображаются так, как должны по задумке вашей или вашего дизайнера, то значит вы всё делаете правильно. Используете ли вы при этом тег `<tbody>` не имеет решающего значения.

Да не посетит вас идея отказаться от верстки HTML и вставить картинки в текст писем!

---

Странности вёрстки писем HTML Academy можно объяснить шаблонами MailChimp. У них вы не можете вот так просто поменять HTML писем - остаётся пользоваться тем что есть. Благо их стандартные шаблоны всюду работают.